# draw some irregular water like riverb using three js in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

i wanted to create irregular water river which i try in three js example also but nothing show like that

i am try to adding the shape and then apply the but nothing to show like that, please help me where i could mistake

````
import { Water } from "three/examples/jsm/objects/Water.js";
import waternormals from "../assets/waternormals.jpg";

const RiverCanel = () => {
  
>! const watertexture = textureLoader.load(
>! waternormals,
>!     (texture) => (texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping)
>! 

 
 const pentaGeometry =  new THREE.BufferGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100);
 
  const waterobj = new Water(
    pentaGeometry,
    {
      scale: 0.1,
      textureWidth: 512,
      textureHeight: 512,
      flowSpeed: 0.04,
      reflectivity: 0.35,
      waterNormals: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
            "../assets/waternormals.jpg",
            function (texture) {
              // texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
              texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
              texture.repeat.set(5, 5);
            }
          ),
      color: 'blue',
    }  );
 
  waterobj.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

  return waterobj;
};

export default RiverCanel;```
````